Venting crawl space while also mitigating radon
I live in southern Indiana.  Moderate temperatures year round, moist in the summer, dry in the winter.  I have a full basement under most of my house and a crawl space under the rest of it.  The basement is fully conditioned and the crawl space walls are sealed and insulated with about 2" of closed cell foam.  There is new plastic on the crawl space floor (which is just dirt) that is part of an addition we just added in a remodel and a much larger area that existed previously where the plastic is pretty old and tore up.
The larger crawl space area floor is a large rock hit when digging the basement.  It was left as-is and the walls of the crawl space were poured on top of it.
In order to keep the crawl space from ever becoming too moist, we vented some of the conditioned air out of a duct on one end of the crawl space and then opened a return duct on the other end so that there was always air circulating in that area.
Unfortunately, I've found out that there is a lot of radon in the house now and I'm sure its due to the the rock and dirt in the crawlspace and venting that air into the living area as well as whatever amount is coming in through the concrete floor.
Radon systems that go through the floor are designed to be pulling air from under the concrete, so no loss of HVAC air there and we don't really care if its moist there.  However, if I start venting the air out of the crawlspace area, I have to get that air from somewhere.

Getting it from outside results in extra moisture in summer and cold air in the winter which could cause pipes to freeze and the floor to be very cold.
Using conditioned air and just venting outside seems like a pretty big waste and expense over the long haul.  Not to mention the air inside the house needs to come from somewhere.

Is #2 my only option?  What am I missing?

Unless the whole crawl space is enclosed and you spring for a heat recovery ventilator, those seem to be the two options. Question: Do you know that you have a radon issue? Testing is inexpensive;.I established that it was present in my basement but at a level that wasn't significant unless I was going to use the basement as living space. Might be worth my addressing if I ever get serious about using the workshop, but otherwise not worth the cost to me.

Yes.  The radon is 30+ (supposed to be under 2) and we spend a lot of time down here.

Ok, that's reason for concern... and reason for paying for a professional's advice rather than seeing opinion from questionably qualified volunteers who will be near your place and can't advise in local conditions and options suited to your needs.
